# How to delete an answered question?

Tags: discussion

Is there any way to delete an answered question? I recently found that the question I've posted is incorrect and got downvotes. When I tried to delete that question, I found someone answered something irrelevant to my question. It also got downvoted.

My problem is,now I cannot delete that question since it possess answers(it is totally irrelevant). I even flagged it to moderator to get deleted. But I didn't get any response. The flag is still active. How should I delete an answered question?

Comment: Are you referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110995/how-to-get-public-ip-address-using-php? Then that answer is not irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 9):

You can delete an answered question.  You *cannot* delete a question that has an answer *with a positive score*, or an accepted answer, or more than one answer.  This is by design.  These conditions indicate that there is value in that post, and we don't want valuable content removed from the site, so you can't delete it.

Even a moderator will not delete such a post, unless they feel that there is compelling evidence that there is no value in the question or any of the answers (and they'll generally be fairly conservative in such judgements).

When you submit content to the site you're giving SE the right to host that content publicly, forever.  You cannot revoke that right.

Comment: so,if that question has negative score answers, then can I delete it?

Comment: And of course that is why you want to make extra sure you don't post company secrets to this site.

Comment: @Ganesh If there are no answers with a positive score, you can delete the question, yes.  That's what I said.

Comment: @Servy: I don't believe that's accurate: as described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/176330), `You can't delete any question that has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)`

Comment: @DavidRobinson Right, I always forget that case.

Comment: @demo: If it's credentials and such, SE will gladly help you to prune it from their copy. They cannot do anything about anyone who got it by then though.