# Getting down votes to an closed Question after one years

Tags: support, specific-question, downvotes, old-questions

One year earlier I asked a question without any code and got down vote. Then I supplied what I had done. But recently I got down vote for that question. This down vote does not make any sense to me.

Question link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25476436/2317535

Comment: Read: [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252740/1842065)

Comment: How to get rid of that question?

Comment: I presume you've tried the "delete" link. If that doesn't work then unaccept the answer and try again.

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman See [How to delete an answered question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255012/how-to-delete-an-answered-question)

Comment: Thanks @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå but i accept that answer, would I remove accept.

Comment: If you want to delete the question then you have to unaccept the answer. It's the way that the system works.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisF I removed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it fair?

Considering there were already 5 downvotes on your question at the time it was asked, I'd say it's fair. Someone happened upon your question and agreed with the other downvoters, so they added their vote. That's perfectly normal.

Normally the response to downvotes is to see how you can improve your post. It's not immediately obvious to me how you would go about fixing this particular question though. It's closed as too broad, but as I'm not familiar with the problem I can't advise how you might narrow it down.

Maybe the community will see fit to put your question out of its misery — you'll get back any rep you lost to the downvotes when that happens. That answer looks vaguely useful, but at the same time I don't know if any real value would be lost by deleting your question. Your frustration is understandable.

Comment: Considering he could have cleaned it up if he had wanted to (and it would have been deleted if he hadn't stopped that), it's more than fair. Assuming the question deserves that fate.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Based on the comments it seems he was unaware he could unaccept the answer and delete the question. Hell, it didn't occur to *me* he could do that either until ChrisF mentioned it. It doesn't matter whether the OP wants to if the OP doesn't know how to go about it. But now the OP knows, and has gone through with it, so all is well.

Comment: Well, if one knows what to do, most things become trivial. And in this case not even laborious.