# Should "revenge downvotes" on questions be more expensive?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, downvotes

I have read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303808/getting-down-votes-to-an-closed-question-after-one-years) answer; but that is about a question that was downvoted 5 times before; not what I have on my mind.

But I am coming from a similar thought: I think I have seen more than once some "revenge" downvotes on a question of mine: there is a question, maybe not exactly great; but also not bad (no downvotes when asked; or maybe one down, one up). Some answers come in; I accept something. Fine.

And then, out of the blue sky, months or years later, that question gets a downvote (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791289/best-ways-to-manipulate-getfacl-output)). I rarely see that on answers, but most often on questions, leading to that hard feeling that somebody just wants to "punish" me for something I said somewhere... and goes the cheapest way - by downvoting a question for free.

And I am simply wondering: would it make sense to make that at least one bit more expensive? Or is that just something to live with?

On "why I feel it is *revenge*" - very simple: That ONE question downvote is the *exception*. But I have seen two or three times this year that 3 to 5 of my questions go -2 within 10 minutes. But of course, that is "not enough of a pattern" when asking a moderator to look into.

And then: I accepted answers. I simply **hate** the idea that I delete such a question of mine, just to keep up that positive question track record.

Comment: How do you know it's a revenge downvote and not [Tim Post's cat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/295232)?

Comment: @Glorfindel How do you know it's Tim Post's cat and not OP himself (which appears to be a cat as well)?

Comment: As said; it is guessing. And I have experienced serial downvoting already; so I am just sensitive to that. One of the consequences is that I already self-censor myself and avoid criticizing people beyond "downvote reputation level". But thing is: I try to give comments on most of my downvotes or close requests. And then see my update to the question.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Maybe because he understands that I cant downvote my content myself.

Comment: You know, that "And if you really liked what I am doing; feel free to upvote ;-)" bit in your profile description just might rub some people the wrong way and give them a reason to do the exact opposite... Just saying.

Comment: Revenge Downvotes shouldn't be expensive, they should be reverted. Since it is hardly possible to detect actual revenge downvotes, that can't be realized. And downvoting a question due to its quality, shouldn't cost anything.

Comment: @Gimby Both happens. But the thing is: my first serial downvoting came in because I dared to tell somebody: your answer doesnt make any sense. That was enough to turn that person made. Luckily, that time, that was a person not knowing the system. He engaged in a serial downvote, which was detected; and in the end uncovered a schema by that person using a sock puppet ... and not liking people telling him that his bogus answers were c**p. But it seems that other people are smarter. So my takeaway from your comment is: dont put comments anymore? Just silently downvote and move on?

Comment: There is no such thing as a _"a serial downvote"_. "Serial downvoting", on the other hand, exists.

Comment: I, for my opinion, would be really happy to get some comments on the downvoted questions. So that I can improve them to make them more usefull. It don't has to be more expensive. If everyone who downvotes is **forced** to leave a comment it would be much more helpfull I think.

Comment: @theoretisch I think there are **tons** and **tons** of discussions around the topic of "enforced" comments. And I think the community long ago decided that they dont want that. But well, in such scenarios, I think they really would make sense.

Comment: @GhostCat Yes I know. It has some disadvantages too but as you said, in such scenarios it would help.

Comment: @GhostCat Yes, but I think it should be possible to set the author of the special comments to unknown. So that for example only the mods have the possibility to see the real Author in case that the comment is inappropriate.

Comment: @theoretisch And then people would write down kinda empty statements. You see, questions currently at zero most likely expose one or the other weakness.

Comment: @GhostCat This is one of the disadvantages. All the inapropriate or empty comments have to be removed. But then the mods can see who votes down without any reason, and can inflict some punishment.

Comment: @theoretisch By "empty" I meant: you sure write down something that looks reasonable. I guess such a solution could dramatically increase the work load on our moderators.

Comment: @GhostCat Yes, but I think most of the "revenge-downvoters" are to lazy to conceive something for every question even if its "empty". Whatever, something like that will never be implemented. But its sad that there are so many of this people that we have to think about something like that.

Comment: Targeted voting sucks quite heavily, nothing quite corrupts the system as badly.  It can auto-detect a lot of it but it aims to be as accurate as possible and users have learned how to bypass it.  Your profile does not stand up well to close scrutiny.  Normalizing this so that other SO users don't feel compelled to correct voting anomalies by themselves does have to start somewhere.  Don't do it.

Comment: @HansPassant I am sorry. I don't get what you mean by *Normalizing this*. Is this a suggestion to me to do something about my profile; or any kind of activities? Honestly, you comment really confuses me; I am pretty much lost about what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: Personally, I downvote bad posts whenever I happen to see them. I don't care if it's an old post. I stumble across old content all the time in the course of searching for things.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Please don't.

There are **so many** bad questions out there. I'm not interested in being "punished" for downvoting low quality questions. Votes are a quality control mechanism.

Only a small minority of downvotes on questions are revenge downvotes. Don't "punish" the majority for those.

Comment: I get you. Still it *sucks* to see my "question record" go down by 5 or 10 over half a year. So, the answer is: I just downvote other stuff; and stop giving comments. Hurra ;-(

Comment: @GhostCat *"and stop giving comments"* You hardly gain something for commenting anyway. Either a bunch of downvotes, some lame excuses ("was in a hurry" -.-) or other non-sense. I only comment if I "know" the user and expect them to care for their answer and expect an update to improve it.

Comment: @Tom And I find that to be one of the "worst" practices on SO. I know that there have been many discussions around here; but I have made the experience that just a short sentence helps many folks, too.

Comment: But one question on your answer: how often do you downvote **bad** questions that have not been touched for 6, 12, ... months?

Comment: @GhostCat That can happen if one finds that question while using a search engine (or it has been linked, for example as a dupe of another one) and one finds the question bad. But I can't tell how often that happens.

Comment: @GhostCat: A couple of times each month.

Comment: Thanks God most people upvoted this answer. I almost fainted when I saw the question with a positive score.

Comment: @Oriol I think the interesting aspect in there is: why make time zones such a difference? But alas, fine with me. I learned a lot of things today; so thanks for for all the feedback.

Comment: @GhostCat it also seems that short sentences get you downvoted if peiple disagree... Sounds like a risk you have to be willing to take if you are to comment. It's bad and shouldn't be done that way.... But I can't think of a way to stop these that wouldn't discourage overall voting

Comment: It's ironic that folks think they are hurting the person who they are revenge downvoting.  But in reality it is actually hurting the people that come to this site to find answers and may determine that the downvote means the answer isn't very good.  In general, downvotes are rare and if you get one up vote it will negate 5 downvotes so there is no reason worrying about it.  If everyone would just take the votes with a grain of salt and focus on giving good answers, they would be better off.