# Is there any "secret" information kept about users ... that only moderators can see?

Tags: discussion, users, moderators

Yesterday I had the stupid idea of telling a user that his question was too broad and off-topic, and well, a bit naive (yes, that second part wasn't a good thing) to explain my downvote and close request. 5 min later, his question was closed, then deleted by him; and 15 minutes later I had a full serial downvote going on.

Reputation is back this morning, guy has a -275 fine imposed on him; alright then.

Now I am wondering: are such *incidents* kept somewhere? What I mean is: when people are "unhappy" edit reviewers, they get banned at some point. And they get banned for a longer period when it happens again.

So, in other words: is there some "secret incident" record that moderators have access to, in order to understand: "user X was doing 3 serial downvotes over the course of the last 24 months" for example?

And if so—is there a way that a user can look into "his own" incident record?

Comment: The real question is, did you get a hat for being serially downvoted?

Comment: Not that I am aware of :-)... But maybe I am hat-banned due to the negative reception I received upon my Christmas hat question here the other day... :-) x2

Comment: The other question that comes up naturally here: is there a hat for serial downvoters? And would it be mandatory for them to wear it for 4 weeks? But maybe we better not go there...

Comment: FWIW… http://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement :)

Comment: @GhostCat  ..."And would it be mandatory for them to wear it for 4 weeks" - ROFL!  :-)  If only...!

Comment: Not even admins can see.

Comment: @GhostCat That is why I proposed an optional downvote reason. Currently you cannot anonymously tell the user why you dislike his question/answer. If you could select from a list of options this could work as a feedback.

Comment: @GhostCat Yes, but it's mandatory to wear during 6 to 8 weeks.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Sure, moderators have access to quite a bit of information that isn't public otherwise. As deceze points out, it's why we have to sign [a strict agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) that dictates how we can and cannot use this information. This includes an easily accessible record of all kinds of historical information about a user.

It's public knowledge that moderator messages and annotations stay with a user account, and you can imagine that the vote invalidations you see publicly in your reputation history leave similar annotations for all involved.

A user's history is a very important factor in how we deal with someone when we come across problematic behavior. If we see someone serially downvoting another person, but they haven't done anything like this before, we'll typically explain to them why that's frowned upon and warn them not to do it again. If they've done this to more than one person, or have been warned about it before, we start escalating the response based on their history.

For obvious reasons, moderator annotations and specific information about vote invalidation, etc. are hidden from the annotated user. Notes from one moderator to others about the way to track someone's sock puppets or patterns of bad behavior to watch for are not things we'd like specific users to be aware of.

When I handled your flag yesterday, I could see the history for both of the accounts involved here and act on this in a way that I thought would best prevent future incidents. I could see that there was no history between you two, that this was triggered by a single post, and hopefully was just a temporary bit of bad judgment. Were this to happen again, we could see the action that was taken yesterday and we would handle it differently based on that history.

Comment: Thank you very much for this enlightening piece of information and transparency! Just wondering: how often does something like that yesterday happen? 5 times per day... Or more like once a week?

Comment: @GhostCat - Us warning people about revenge downvoting? Maybe 2-3 times a week. It's less prevalent than plagiarism, which [itself is less common than voting fraud](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/331936/19679).

Comment: More insidious is "slight" serial revenge downvoting: got the same problem as the OP the other day, and I suspect the guy downvoted 2 of my high-voted questions (unrelated: c & python) at the same time. I flagged, but nothing happened.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Dont expect anything to happen there. 2 incidents always mean "not enough of a pattern". And basically, there is nothing that we can do about that; or that looks worth to the community to do about it (see that other, less positively received question of mine that I put up just some days earlier: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339916/should-revenge-downvotes-on-questions-be-more-expensive )

Comment: user just took advantage of the serial downvoting limit. I don't complain, since a few days after that, I got 2 upvotes on totally unrelated good answers of mine. Somehow small serial upvoting makes up for serial downvoting, but that does fix _rep_, not the appreciation of the downvoted questions.

Comment: BTW I don't expect anything. It's just that if I see this ***** again posting something, I'll downvote his post if it's average, where I wouldn't have done anything if it was anyone else. Not very constructive, I admit. I forgot to tell you that I didn't downvote him in the first place: just flagged his question as a duplicate (to help him!). That's why I'm so pissed!

Answer (score 20):

Serial downvotes [are largely handled by automated scripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/175248).  Only in the case of the script failing to rectify the fraudulent votes would a moderator get involved.

The details of whether or not they've got that kind of information are kept pretty close to the chest; while I personally doubt that a user doing those serial downvotes would be looked at beyond the initial punishment for their offense, I have little doubt in my mind that they'd keep track of *some* history.

That said, I also doubt you can look into details of an "incident record" as it were.  I'd wager that if you were in trouble with the moderators, you'd know about it by now.