# Duplicate question and answer from user in same location

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers, duplicate-accounts

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41345570/5233410) post is exact duplicate of [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/667781/5233410).

[Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41345701/5233410) is also copied and pasted from [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540895/5233410) on duplicate post.

Both users are from same location with the aswerer being a new account. 6 days as of this post.

suspect that one may be trying to game the rep system.

UPDATE:

After calling out the post it was deleted and then the new account changes it name and location.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328914

Comment: And now the duplicate has been deleted by the original poster. You were right to trust your nose here; this is obviously shady on any number of levels. But it could have been adequately handled by raising a custom moderator flag.

Comment: Raised the flag but they deleted the post soon after. now one account changed name and location and then asked new question with both accounts again. http://stackoverflow.com/q/41345988/5233410

Comment: If you used a custom flag, deletion won't affect anything. The moderator will still see your flag, and like all 10k+ users, moderators can see deleted questions. Feel free to flag the new question, too.

Comment: Will do. thanks for the info.

Comment: Good job noticing this! I hope this problem is fairly contained and I'm not just blind because I've never seen this before.

Comment: It happens more often than you would think, @merlin. Plagiarism and vote fraud are two of the most common issues tackled by our moderators. Luckily, they all take it seriously, and we have several that are *especially* on the ball when it comes to handling it. See, for example, [Brad's answer and comments here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340263/366904).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should raise a moderator flag on the answer you saw. Make sure to include in your note accompanying the flag that:

1. The answer was plagiarized from another SO answer. Provide a link to the source from which it was plagiarized. I would also take a look at other answers from the same user to check for plagiarism because if a user did it once, chance are they did it more than once. (Note that this is *sufficient* on its own to raise a flag.)
2. If you think there was collusion between the OP and the answerer, present your evidence. Having the same location in their profile is not decisive but moderators can see more information than we do.

You should also vote to close the question as a duplicate of the question from which the answer was plagiarized. (Some of us started doing this before the OP decided to delete, maybe you did too. Just mentioning it for completeness.)

Comment: Agreed. Still haven't mastered the whole flagging process properly. As for the location, it just felt odd given the suspicious nature of the post that they had the exact same location. And then the answerer proceeded to change name and location after being called out on it. I guess that is for the moderator to figure out.