# How to deal with a politically motivated edit which doesn't break anything?

Tags: discussion, specific-edit

So I came across the following edit:

[image]

I was intrigued by the superfluous nature of the edit so I took a gander at the user's profile and it seems that they are based in Pakistan (I presume the edit was made because of the India vs Pakistan rivalry). Nevertheless, my questions are:

- The edit doesn't fundamentally change the code or make it non-working however it absolutely is a useless edit as such, should it be rolled back or should it be left to prevent a potential rollback war?
- In scenarios like this should the mods handle it over a normal user?

Comment: As if we don't have enough problems already to moderate stuff here ... let's not do politics here .... flag for a moderator.

Comment: It is a useless edit that probably follows a political agenda. Flag for moderator attention so they can have a word with the editor.

Comment: On a second look, the edits definitely make the post wrong. "Pakistan" is not a string of length 5.

Comment: @BDL good spot. Rolling back.

Comment: Curiously, it doesn't seem like there is a pattern of this user doing this kinda of thing. Their edits are not usually the best, but generally not that bad either. Maybe they were just having a silly day.

Comment: It's a superfluous edit *at best*. I don't see a reason to approve it even if it was correct.

Comment: @VLAZ the author is 2K+ so it doesn't need approval.

Comment: @Script47 ah, I missed that detail. This probably brings up the question - are 2k+ edits allowed to be superfluous? Not just "very minor" improvements but actively a non-factor.

Comment: @VLAZ no, they can't be superfluous. All edits - irrespective of rep - should be useful and purposeful.

Comment: @yivi Yeah, looks like the editor was just being silly. The company referenced in the answer is located in Ottapidaram, India, about the furthest point in India from Pakistan as possible.

Comment: @yivi I'm pretty sure it's because of the recent match between India and Pakistan, https://www.icc-cricket.com/match/8213#scorecard , the user was not in the right mind at the moment and made that decision on a whim.

Comment: Even ignoring the fact that it _literally_ makes the answer wrong, I would personally flag that as spam/vandalism.

Comment: @jhpratt No - the goal of the edit suggester was to change the country names *without harming the content*. The harm what he did was unintentional.

Comment: I'd just change it to a non-related country of length 5, e.g. Chile, or a fictional one, e.g. Endor. Keeps the politics out :)

Comment: @Sabito,
*Just because 'rollback war' words appear in a post doesn't mean that the post is about rollback wars.*
– Point taken. You were right to roll back this one. My mistake.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

It's an entirely superfluous edit, and as @BDL points out:

> [..] the edits definitely make the post wrong. "Pakistan" is not a string of length 5.

This would fall under the category of "no improvement" and/or "vandalism" either way, so rolling it back was correct. I've put a note on the user which will influence future moderation decisions, should they show any such problematic behaviour again. So far the user's behaviour seems innocent enough, so let's give them the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: `I've put a note on the user` First time I hear about this feature! Is there anywhere we can be informed about such notes? I'd really like to know if I am on a 'watch list' and for what reasons.

Comment: Oh, *you* especially. [✌️](http://l2.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/Rl8o0R1XmBlaaSq1KhuOlw--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7cT04NTt3PTQ1MA--/http://l.yimg.com/os/251/2013/08/16/meet-the-parents-gif_175852.gif) But, well, no, it’s moderator internal stuff, so shush. 

Comment: It’s like back in school, where the teacher tells you, “This is going on your *permanent record*, young man.” (I hope that’s not too much of an Americanism.) We have that here, too, @user. And, no, there’s no Freedom of Information Act that allows you to request a viewing of your own record. Super seekrit is super seekrit.

Comment: @CodyGray: Not even GDPR? Isn't this personal information about someone?

Comment: @user000001 the first rule of moderator notes is don't talk about moderator notes...

Comment: On top of this, the website for that content, https://www.qualitypointtech.com/, mentions that it is located in India, giving an additional mark against the edit.

Comment: Chances are it's just a mild ribbing between friends or co-workers that got way too much attention here.  I could totally see that kind of thing happening with a sports team.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, @user000001, and I don't even live in the EU, so I really can't comment on what GDPR requires. However, I will say that I don't think so. It isn't really personal information being tracked here. Rather, it is one moderator's subjective opinion, a note from one moderator to a future moderator. You are, of course, entitled to use the "contact" page to submit a request to the team.

Comment: I'd feel a lot better if somebody pinged the user with this meta question.

Comment: @Joshua Why? The problem has been resolved. It could, in fact,  have been easily resolved without the intervention of either a moderator or Meta. There's no reason to make an even bigger deal of it.

Comment: @CodyGray: There was this long debate at work that boiled down to "If you think my behavior needs to change you need to actually talk to me about it." So yeah, I'm kinda sensitive to deciding something is a behavior problem and not even talking to the user in question. Maybe a bit much though.

Comment: Makes me wonder how many notes i have!

Comment: @Joshua Likely nothing will come of this. I don’t think it’s really a politically motivated act at all. If the user never does anything to raise an eyebrow ever again, this will have been a NOOP. Just, *if* they ever seriously start transgressing, we have some more evidence to fall back on. As such, no need to contact them about anything just yet.

Comment: And in general: no, the annotation feature isn’t used a whole lot. Most users don’t have any “record”. Mostly what lands on your record are suspensions and direct moderator messages, which are self-explanatory enough.

Comment: @CodyGray I've downloaded my personal data a while ago and user annotations about me weren't in there, and I know I have some. if i recall correctly about a prior discussion, the rationale SE relies on to withhold annotations is that they're a trade secret of the site, which I guess is fair. They're definitely PI though, as in conjunction with my name/identity, it's information about me. "Magisch has foo'd way too many bars and will be suspended next time" is personal information just like "Magisch has green eyes", imo.

Comment: _\*Scribbles down "@Magisch: green eyes"\*_

Comment: Maybe no need to contact the user, but since this got chosen as a hot question, the user might well see it anyway, even if they don't normally track Meta.

Comment: @Magisch there is a difference between your personal information and an opinion of you (which is a personal information of someone having an opinion!). A company is not required to disclose their opinion of you (except in some narrow cases, like they have to disclose your credit score when reporting the status of your credit application). I can see notes failing squarely into opinion category

Comment: @SergeyA, IANAL, but I'm pretty confident you're wrong here. Totally anecdotal, but I'm under the impression that notes about a candidate at interview (for example) are considered PI under GDPR (https://www.xperthr.co.uk/faq/do-job-applicants-have-the-right-to-see-notes-made-on-them-at-interview/59213/), and I can't see how these annotations would be substantially different. Hopefully SO's lawyers have already considered this; if not, I think they should. Although, of course, we know that SO staff don't read Meta, so I'm not sure why I'm bothering to say it here :)

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave it's not nearly as clear cut. The CJEU decided in YS v Minister voor Immigratie that legal analysis of a person is not in itself personal data, even though it contains personal data. Their reasoning included that the right to access was the foundation for verifying accuracy and thus for rectification and erasure rights, but access to the legal analysis was not necessary for this purpose. Does Article 15 of the GDPR change this? Are internal notes protected by the exception in Article 15.4?  Recitals 60, 63 seem to indicate that notes are PII, but recitals aren't law...

Comment: @thebjorn, I realise it's not clear cut - it's the law after all, that's _never_ clear cut :) It just feels like a feature that has the potential to cause difficulties. This scenario is probably a good example - if the note that was left in this case mentions the (assumed) location of the editor (however course-grained), would that make it PII? I've no idea, but my money would be on 'yes'. It's obviously moot, because I'm sure the lawyers will have considered it, and even if they haven't, me whining about it here won't cause them to.

Comment: @deceze where could I submit a request about clearing all the moderator notes connected with my profile, according to the GDPR?

Comment: @Tarasovych That is above my pay grade; ask a separate question about that. But as noted above, whether that falls under the GDPR or not is rather debatable.

Comment: "Manage data required to maintain the service" is a thing, right? You can ask for mod notes to be deleted and they will delete it: along with your account. (Cc @Tarasovych)

Comment: @Andras I would agree. It's not your name, or address, or phone number, or anything else. I believe people try to slap "GDRP" on things that aren't applicable. But of course IANAL, so I can't speak authoritatively on that point at all.

Comment: @AndrasDeak there is nothing about moderator notes in the Privacy Policy. So, let me help to answer your question about the thing. Can a thing be invisible?

Comment: @Tarasovych You should really open a new topic if you want to discuss the applicability of the GDPR. I'd start with pointing you here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340263/476.

Comment: @deceze "personal data means _any_ information relating to an identified or identifiable natural person.." Art. 4 GDPR (emphasis mine). So any idea that PII is only name/address/phone is definitely not even close to correct - if it extends to moderator notes is an interesting general question - ie. does the deliberative work of the data processor fall under Art 15 [right to access] or is it only the "results". At this point we're way into lawyer land so this discussion really is moot. Tarasovych can of course file an art 14/17 (access/erasure) through proper channels and SO must reply...

Comment: @thebjorn This is really really off topic here and I urge anyone to open a separate topic about it, but what about all the other data which is surely attached to the account out of necessity, say—hypothetically—encryption keys generated by the system for your account? Could it be used to identify you? Maybe. It that reasonable to divulge on request? No. Just food for thought, as you say, this is a topic for the lawyers, not for an aside in a comment thread.

Comment: A note available to moderators that is specifically associated with a given user is absolutely, incontrovertibly, personal information subject to GDPR. The privacy policy needs to reveal that such information is being maintained and why, and what procedures are available for discovering its existence and challenging its accuracy. It's as sensitive as a credit rating.

Comment: @Michael et al: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/42433/9788

Comment: @Magisch You actually don’t have any annotations. Not to say that your conclusion is wrong; I’m pretty sure these will *not* be in the data dump. But we haven’t inscribed any of our backroom gossip about you in your permanent record. ;-)

Comment: @CodyGray I remembered someone telling me they put one on me, but It might have been facetious or faulty memory. They dont age away iirc.

Comment: @Magisch I _think_ they go away when an account is true-deleted. (They're certainly inaccessible.) So, they _sort of_ age away. But, yeah, if you want to use Stack Overflow et al., Stack Overflow needs to store account-related data in association with your account.

Answer (score 6):

An edit's not just about "not making the post worse", it should *actively make the post better*.

So given that, I think there's a very clear rejection reason:

[image: No improvement]

Comment: There's still the question of "no improvement" vs "vandalism" (intentional harm).

Comment: The OP was 2K+ therefore this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Could be either in this case, but "no improvement" is the clear, safe option in general cases like this.