# Is asking for angular JS tools ... not offtopic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Just came over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680693/tool-to-organize-translations-in-json-files) question: *Is there any tool that can read local translation files and is able to show different translations side-by-side for each key? Either an application (Mac OS support is a must) or browser-based.*

8 upvotes, zero close requests.

Now I am wondering (again): is my assumption (offtopic!) correct, or is the silent majority correct that viewed this question before ... and that didn't do anything about it?

Comment: There *were* close votes, but they aged away. I've closed the post now.

Comment: This actually happens pretty regularly. Blatant find/rec requests will get up voted and/or avoid closure because of 1) low views, 2) those who saw it are unfamiliar with site rules, 3) those who saw it wanted rep from answering it, 4) those who saw it wanted to promote their product/company, and 5) those who saw it also wanted to know the answer. It doesn't help when the asker is someone with relatively high rep, which makes the new users answering assume the question is OK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's off-topic. Votes are meaningless when determining whether a question is on- or off-topic.

Comment: Well, they *mean* that somebody preferred clicking the "up arrow" instead the "close" link.

Comment: @GhostCat: not everyone that can vote up can also vote to close. Not everyone that votes understands what is on-topic on the site. Something can also be off-topic and still be well asked and perhaps be deserving of an upvote. Etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Makes sense. Maybe we should work on a system that reduces each user to like "1 rep" one day per quarter; just to remember us what exactly having "0 privileges" really means. Talk about "living in a bubble" here ...

Comment: @GhostCat: [Do what Shog9 does](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65609/140890) and create a new account once in a while.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So far, I stayed away from that (although some folks I have some "elves" doing that for me http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339916/should-revenge-downvotes-on-questions-be-more-expensive ) ... mainly to avoid the temptation to in the end ... try to fix my not so great "question track" ;-) but I get the point. Thanks!

Comment: Joining a new Stack Exchange community is also an enlightening experience and a good way to pop your reputation bubble, @ghostcat. Of course, it isn't quite the same, because other sites are not quite so overrun with drivel as Stack Overflow, and they are small enough that their diamond moderators take care of it quickly with minimal impact.

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, I asked my first question on another SE site recently and it's a humbling experience. I even went to their chat and Meta to make sure my question would be on-topic, afraid to make a mistake.

Comment: Every time one of my questions got closed for being offtopic, I wondered why so many very similar questions did not seem to be offtopic in the first place (like most JavaScript and React questions that are still open). For as a still not so familiar user, this feels like arbitrary gatekeeping to keep newbies out, even though I appreciate that that does not reflect the moderators' intention. Same reason I stopped contributing to Wikipedia long ago. Too much gatekeeping, too many haters. Maybe also the reason STEM is still dominated by white male first wold guys? Just wanted to share my feeling.