# How to delete my own noisy questions that have answers?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently wrote a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333622/how-to-access-static-constants-to-a-python-class) on SO that was a very bad move. I asked for help to identify my mistake while it was no mistake at all. My question is thus the answer to it.

The only answer that point out my mistake prevent me to remove my question.

I understand from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255012/how-to-delete-an-answered-question) that even a moderator cannot delete a question.

How to proceed in this case?

Comment: When the answer gets enough downvotes, or the question gets enough close-votes, deletion should be possible, I think. That said, the answer should just have been a comment instead.

Comment: We're working on it. Don't mind the additional downvotes please, these are part of the process. As soon your question is put on hold, and has 3  downvotes or more, we can send it to the delete queue.

Comment: Moderators certainly *can* delete a question, they are just not that eager to strip rep from answerers.   Ultimately this is up to the [python] community, if they upvote answers like that and don't cast the obvious close-vote then it sticks around.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think that questions that were asked by mistake, overlooking a typo will ever be useful for future research. Python community or not.

Comment: No argument from me, I close-voted.  You need to address the python community.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, the [tag:python] community seems to be much more lax on keeping crap out, than we are in [tag:c++] ;-)

Comment: There's quite a few of the python community over in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python if you want to talk :)  There's normally a few discussions of question closure in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to proceed in this case?

As verified here, the best way seems to bring it up on Meta Stack Overflow and get a broader audience, who is interested in site moderation.

You cannot delete a question that received upvoted answers yourself, there's literally no way you can handle this without help of the community.

The process is

1. The question is down and close voted
2. As soon there are more than 3 downvotes on the question and it's put [on hold] (5 +3k users need to agree) ...
3. ... users above 20k rep can send it to the deletion queue
4. As soon three of them agree your question gets deleted.

Glad we've been on service to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer received enough downvotes to bring it's score down to `0`, just now.

This means that delete-votes on the question have been unlocked. With the attention the post will get through this meta discussion, the question should be deleted in [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514).

Comment: No I still cannot delete it `This question has answers`

Comment: Done now. @nowox you can't, but we can ;-) ...

Comment: _@Cerbrus_ 6-8 weeks seems to be a very conservative destination ;-)

Comment: ^ s/destination/estimation

Comment: Wut, why'd this get a downvote? o.o

Comment: @Cerbrus _"why'd this get a downvote?"_ Because it was just a part of the process, but didn't actually answer the (obviously good) question. Sorry ;-) ...

Comment: The answer is incorrect in the "delete votes have been unlocked". Users with 10K rep can vote to delete  questions regardless of the score of the answers.  The author of the question still cannot delete it if there is an _upvote_ on the answer; it doesn't matter how many downvotes are there. This is just how that particular check is [implemented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74471).

Comment: @NormalHuman: That is incorrect. Downvotes weren't available when the answer had a positive score, but opened up _immediately_ after the downvote required to make it's score `0`. From your link: _"You can only one-click delete when <...> your question has only one answer with **no upvotes**"_

Comment: Yes, it does say ***no upvotes***. I repeat: it says ***no upvotes***. And it means ***no upvotes***. Not "zero score".

Comment: @NormalHuman: Your whore argument is based on your interpretation of some rules from a 2011 blog post, about site functions you've never used. My answer is based on actually using those tools that you are nowhere near to having the rep for. The delete vote appeared when the answer no longer had a positive score. Simple as that.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think you meant to say "whole" not "whore" ;)

Comment: Eh, whoops, I did xD