# The process to delete an answered question does not make any sense!

Tags: discussion, bug, deleted-questions

I read this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255013/7579632)

> You can delete an answered question. You cannot delete a question that
>   has an answer with a positive score, or an accepted answer, or more
>   than one answer. This is by design. These conditions indicate that
>   there is value in that post, and we don't want valuable content
>   removed from the site, so you can't delete it.

How ever none of this is obvious when you try to delete your own post. This is the first message I get when clicking delete:

> **Delete this answered question?**
>
> We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so
>   deprives future readers of this knowledge.
>
> Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account
>   being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?

Then when I press the delete button, it says:

> You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and
>   effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center.

The point here is why you give a warning and the consequence of a question ban (the first message) if I don't have the choice anyway.

You might as well show the second message directly. and save me the time of pressing the button again thinking it is sort of a bug.

Comment: Hard to see the problem.  "Don't do it" and "You can't" are distinct messages.  Surely by now you know why you can't delete it and why shouldn't delete posts in the future.  Mission accomplished.

Comment: @HansPassant the first message is misleading. It gives you the impression that you can delete the question even if it has answers.

Comment: We simply don't trust the OP to be a good judge if their question should be deleted or not. The double action and message is there to scare off the homework cheaters that delete their assignment, I mean question, once someone did their homework for them.

Comment: I'm guessing that popup makes slightly more sense in the case where you have only one answer without a positive score as to warn you off deleting it where you can actually delete it... However, there's no harm always displaying it anyway to remind you that that your action will affect the contributions of others and you should really really really take that into account.

Comment: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/07/01/dont-hide-or-disable-menu-items/

Comment: You get the same dialog when trying to delete a question that you answered yourself. Even when it's the only answer. "others have invested time and effort into answering it", yes me, I answered it, now I want to delete it.

Comment: @JonClements fair points.

Comment: @DaveCarruthers this is from the post I linked: _When you submit content to the site you're giving SE the right to host that content publicly, forever. You cannot revoke that right._

Comment: @JonClements I actually disagree. The harm is in frustrating users. If you can't delete it, just jump straight to the can't delete message. Or maybe combine them into a single message.

Comment: @jpmc26 exactly how I felt about it.

Comment: @NisargShah Or you could avoid making the user do an extra thing, only to find out it's actually impossible, and disable the button, then put a message next to it explaining why it's disabled.